# api examples have bad callback syntax for safari and mobile chrome

Tags: bigcommerce

So in this example, the callback function syntax will break on Safari and mobile Chrome and Safari.

```
utils.api.cart.getContent(options, (err, response) => {
  $modalOverlay.hide();
  $cartCounter.text(response.data.cart.items.length + " items in your cart");
  $modalContent.html(response.content);
});
```

Should be written as ...

```
utils.api.cart.getContent(options, function(err, response) {
  $modalOverlay.hide();
  $cartCounter.text(response.data.cart.items.length + " items in your cart");
  $modalContent.html(response.content);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code examples are using [ES6](http://es6-features.org/) syntax. You can see other examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions